# Static compilation linking Openssl

Tags: c, linker, openssl, static-linking

I'm tryng to compile a program that links openssl library. When I compile dynamically I get no problems. The problems come up when I add -static flag, i get this error :

```
gcc  -g -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++  -o hmac-sha1-bios-x64 ../main.c -lcrypto -lm
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:10: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "hmac-sha1-bios-x64" non riuscito
make: *** [hmac-sha1-bios-x64] Errore 1
```

Has anyone any ideas how to compile statically openssl libraries ?

I looked for some references to libcrypto.a in /usr/lib, but I got only libcrypt.a. I'm working on an archlinux, is it possible the official openssl archlinux package doesn't include the needed files to compiple statically ?

Comment: It probably means there is no static version of `libcrypto`?

Comment: So, the only way to make it work it's to compile by myself the libraries, isn't it ? But it's weird, the official archlinux package is compiled with the shared option, and here (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) it's written : _Build a shared object in addition to the static archive_

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I resolved. During the creation of openssl package, all static libs are deleted. The only way is to download the PKGBUILD, then add the "staticlibs" to the options field :

```
options=('!makeflags' 'staticlibs')
```

In this way the package is rebuild with static libs and it should work.